# get timing as accurate as possible in python

Tags: python, windows, timing

What is the accurates method in Python 3 for timings.
I'm writing a script which communicates with a CAN-Bus and the timings are important for this bustype. At the moment i dont have problems, everything works fine. But i'm trying to tweak the script for a more accurate timing.

For example i use this method:

```
from time import time as get_time

def timing_is_all(miliseconds):
    miliseconds /= 1000
    start = get_time()

    while get_time() - start < milisecond:
        pass
```

I want to call it for 10 miliseconds:

```
timing_is_all(10)
```

Whould it be wiser to use a thread, which runs in the background and changes a global var? Or is the build in function sleep already as close as it gets for timings?

I know realtime is not possible on a system with a OS etc. I'm just looking for "close" method.

Comment: Why do have a need for such accurate timing? Shouldn't the interface and the drivers take care of the protocol specific timings?

Comment: Like i mentioned i dont have problems at the moment. For example i need to response to some frames on the bus, the given timewindow for response is big enough. I tried to talk as fast but as possible but not to fast. So i used the method from the question, but it variates depending on pc use from 10 - 40 ms. It is still all in the window, i just wanted to check if anyone know a clean and fast way in python.